# Not being able to switch the toolbar for a different activity [Fixed]

Tags: android

I am working with two activities here and I want to switch the action bar from the default MainActivity to the one that I want to have in this particular activity that just has a + symbol to add stuff to what will be a notepad, but I can't catch the error, the logcat is empty and I am just trying to figure out how to change the action bar from the one that is currently showing to the one I want.

Here is my activity in which I am trying to get the different action bar to work:

```
package com.example.projetolinguagensprogramacao1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class Notepad extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notepad);
        Toolbar toolbar2 = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listOfnotes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.add_note){
                Toast.makeText(this, "It's Working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Here is the .xml of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.projetolinguagensprogramacao1.Notepad">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listOfnotes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        setNavigationViewListener();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_lembrete, R.id.nav_listacompra, R.id.nav_poupanca, R.id.nav_login, R.id.nav_notepad)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_login: {  
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_notepad: {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Notepad.class));
                break;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }

    private void setNavigationViewListener() {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

}
```

And the .xml file for the + (plus) symbol that I want to show up on the action bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_note"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_symb"
        android:title="Adicionar"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Edit 1:

So instead of looking something like this:
[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

Edit 2: I tried using the same action bar in the main activity and it worked, so it just adds to my confusion as to why it isn't working in the Notepad activity.

Edit 3: Added Main Activity Code, I tried seeing if switching stuff on the `onNavigationItemSelected()` method and it still goes to image number 2. Maybe the problem is here I just can't find it.

Edit 4: I fixed it, I'm so sorry I am an idiot and didn't notice the blatant mistake I had, but thank you to all of you that answered and helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you should create two menu file.xml

menu1(with its items)  for MainActivity and menu2(with its items) for OtherActivity
then in each activity in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method inflate its own menu.xml

[check this code for short answer](https://gist.github.com/mohosyny/7f83fa1b3a54857400f7c330533cc7c4)

[check this  for a mini project](https://github.com/Sanaebadi97/NoteApp-MVVMEx)

Comment: I've done that, both activities, main and notepad have separate menu .xml files, but I don't know why, it doesn't work on the notepad activity, it appears to inherit the other file.
If I test it in the main activity the menu layout works just fine, but if I use it on the notepad activity as shown in the code above it doesn't change it.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried taking out the onCreateOptionsMenu() to see if something changed, but it didn't, then put it back, ran it again and no change.

Comment: did you override onOptionsItemSelected() method in NoteActivity??
if yes show the implementation of this method

Comment: I edited the code, and yes onOptionsItemSelected() already had override. You can check that part of the code up above.

Comment: I just tried something too. I added a random button to the layout and nothing appeared, now I know that you might say that I have the wrong layout, but as it stands I checked multiple times but it just isn't using the layout nor the action bar and I am just getting more confused because I'm not getting any errors. I have other activities, one example is the login, and it's working just fine, biut as for the notepad activity nothing is happening, even though it should.